# WD Elements 1042 usb 3.0 not recognized by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, drivers, external-hard-drive

I have a WD Elements 1042 with usb 3.0, Windows 7, Lenovo notebook and My Computer can't see it. Anyway, it's visible in Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers -> Elements 1042 Properties -> WD Elements 1042 USB Device Properties: Driver Provider: Microsoft / Driver Date 6/21/2006 / Driver Version: 6.1.7600.16385 / Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows. The Update Driver button is off. When I go to the Device Manager -> Disk Drives -> WD Elements 1042 USB Device and I try to update the driver, they tell me "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date." Even so, the hdd is not recognized as an external drive by Windows and not appearing in My Computer. Can please anybody tell me why is that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely it simply not assigned any Drive Letter.

Try this:

1. Go to Start - Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Computer Management
2. Go under "Storage" - Disk Management

Most likely you will see your WD Elements drive shown there, just without any drive letter. Right Click on the Partition (right hand side of the Diskx - Which could be disk1, or disk2, etc) and choose "Change Drive Letter and Paths" and add a new drive letter.

Hope this helps.